# Pay out using stripe with card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am creating a project using stripe and php. I am integrating the stripe and transfer the amount to the card.I am following the offical document of stripe and getting some error

```
$payout = \Stripe\Payout::create([
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'method' => 'instant',
  'destination' => 'card_xyz',
]);
```

Getting Error:

```
No such external account: 19173966
```

https://stripe.com/docs/payouts

Comment: There's not a huge amount to go on here, but I would recommend testing using the test debit cards for Payouts: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#test-debit-card-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to include **source_type** in the request. See if the account already exists.

```
$payout = \Stripe\Payout::create([
  'amount' => 1000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'method' => 'instant',
  'destination' => 'card_xyz',
  'source_type' => 'card',
]);
```